# Запустить два QWidget's в одном QApplication

Tags: python, gui, pyqt5

У меня есть главное окно програми, в котором есть кнопка, при ее нажатии, должно открыться еще одно окно. Проблема в том, что при нажатии на кнопку, окно открывается и сразу закрываеться. Как исправить это?

Вот код **главного окна**:

```
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *
from PyQt5.QtOpenGL import *
from PyQt5.QtCore import *
from PyQt5.QtGui import *
from Config import *
from ButWiz import *
import sys


class QtWinMaker(QtWinMakerConfig):
    def __init__(self, QtApp):
        super().__init__()
        self.initUI()
        self.show()
        self.QtAplication = QtApp

    def initAddButton(self):
        print("")

    def initUI(self):
        self.initWindow()
        print("InitUI")

    def initWindow(self):
        btn = QPushButton("Button", self)
        btn.move(100, 100)
        btn.clicked.connect(self.CallQtAddButton)

        self.setWindowTitle("ProgramTable")
        self.setGeometry(300, 300, 600, 600)

    def CallQtAddButton(self):
        ex = QtAddButton()
        ex.show()
```

Код **второго окна**:

```
import sys
from pathlib import Path
from os.path import basename
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *
from PyQt5.QtGui import *
from PyQt5.QtCore import *


class QtAddButton(QWidget):
    exe_path = ""
    image_path = ""

    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.initUI()

    def initUI(self):
        self.setWindowTitle("Button wizard")
        self.setGeometry(200, 200, 250, 250)
        self.setFixedSize(250, 250)
        self.initLabels()
        self.initButtons()
        self.initFields()

    def initLabels(self):
        head = QLabel("Choose program and image:", self)
        head.move(50, 10)

        choose_exe_text = QLabel("Choose program: ", self)
        choose_exe_text.move(10, 83)

        choose_image_text = QLabel("Choose image:", self)
        choose_image_text.move(10, 113)

        set_name = QLabel("Enter name:", self)
        set_name.move(10, 53)

    def initButtons(self):
        self.choose_exe_btn = QPushButton("Choose pogram.. ", self)
        self.choose_exe_btn.move(100, 80)
        self.choose_exe_btn.clicked.connect(self.chooseProgram)

        self.choose_image_btn = QPushButton("Choose image..    ", self)
        self.choose_image_btn.move(100, 110)
        self.choose_image_btn.clicked.connect(self.chooseImage)

        self.confirm_btn = QPushButton("Confirm", self)
        self.confirm_btn.move(85, 220)
        self.confirm_btn.clicked.connect(self.confirmEvent)

    def initFields(self):
        self.name_field = QLineEdit(self)
        self.name_field.move(100, 53)

    def chooseProgram(self):
        file_dialog = QFileDialog.getOpenFileName(self, "Open...", filter="Executable files (*.exe)",
                                                  initialFilter='Executable files (*.exe)')
        if file_dialog[0]!="":
            self.exe_path = file_dialog[0]
            self.choose_exe_btn.setText(basename(file_dialog[0]))

    def chooseImage(self):
        file_dialog = QFileDialog.getOpenFileName(self, "Open...", filter="Image files (*.png *.jpg *.jpeg *.gif)",
                                                  initialFilter="Image files (*.png *.jpg *.jpeg *.gif)")
        if file_dialog[0] != "":
            self.image_path = file_dialog[0]
            self.choose_image_btn.setText(basename(file_dialog[0]))

    def confirmEvent(self):
        if Path('cnf.txt').is_file():
            file = open("cnf.txt", "a")
        else:
            file = open("cnf.txt", "w")

        if self.name_field.text() != "":
            if self.exe_path != "":
                if  self.image_path != "":

                    file.write(self.name_field.text() + '\n' + self.exe_path + "\n" + self.image_path + "\n")
                    file.close()
                    self.close()
                else:
                    QMessageBox.warning(self, "Warning", "Choose image.")
            else:
                QMessageBox.warning(self, "Warning", "Choose program.")
        else:
            QMessageBox.warning(self, "Warning", "Empty name field.")
```

Код **main**

```
from UI import QtWinMaker
import sys
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *
from PyQt5.QtOpenGL import *
from PyQt5.QtCore import *


app = QApplication(sys.argv)
ex = QtWinMaker(app)
sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

потому-что ex локальная переменная, которая удалятся при выходе из CallQtAddButton

```
import sys
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication, QPushButton, QWidget

class QtAddButton(QWidget): pass

class QtWinMaker(QWidget):
    def __init__(self, QtApp):
        super().__init__()
        QPushButton(self, text='Win2.show').clicked.connect(self.CallQtAddButton)
        self.show()

    def CallQtAddButton(self):
        # Проблема в том, что при нажатии на кнопку, окно открывается и сразу закрываеться
        # ex = QtAddButton()
        # ex.show()
        # Как исправить ето?
        self.ex = QtAddButton()
        self.ex.show()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    ex = QtWinMaker(app)
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: то есть нужно сделать ее глобальной? или как?

Comment: пример я привел ex=Win2() -> self.ex=Win2()

Comment: Спасибо большое)